Shortcut to go back to previous file in IntelliJ
I cannot find a shortcut which brings me to the previous file I was in. I know of this, however, this is too fine grained. It always jumps to the previous cursor location. If I have movied the cursor a lot in a file, this means I have to move through all these positions before it goes to the file where I came from. I want to be ablo to go directly to the file where I came from/was previously.
Is there a shortcut?

You can navigate between Recent Files using the corresponding shortcut: ⌘E on macOS, or Ctrl+E on Windows/Linux. This will open a Recent Files popup showing the recent files on the right and tool windows on the left. (You can also use this shortcut to open windows.
For more information, see the docs
